# Listview filter without using searchview or edittext

Tags: android, listview, search, android-search, android-filter

I have created a list view in android and I already implement search filter by using searchview and charsequence as parameter like this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

so we must type something in searchview.
can anyone tell me please if there is a way to filter the list adapter in android instead of charsequence we use string?so we dont have to type something as parameter but for example `adapter.getFilter().filter("example");`

Comment: your code is ok, this is how `Filter#filter` method should be called

Comment: Obviously it is possible. just call `adapter.getFilter().filter("example")`.